Does a "research proposal" actually make sense in today's world?
When applying for faculty jobs or research positions, you need to write a research proposal.
But the idea of a research proposal is quite silly when you think about it:

Research, by definition, is about discovery, often spontaneous discovery arising from taking a shower, going out for a walk, a good night of sleep, talking to someone over coffee or tea. A research proposal is a myopic way of thinking about doing research. That's the same as saying: "where do you see yourself in the next 5 years." How can you plan to do a certain research, when that very research might depends on a collaborator that you might meet in the future but haven't met yet?

Practically speaking, everyone is doing research not in their proposal, and nobody I know even have a concrete research agenda nowadays. The only exception are people who have siloed themselves in a single research topic/theme and these people are rarer and rarer by the day. For example, I work in the AI/ML space. People are working on ideas that never even existed just a few months ago. For most researchers, I can only imagine their pages and pages of research proposals were tossed out when things like large-language model was suddenly released.

Finally, this research proposal has not been the historical trajectory of research. I cannot imagine von Neumann or Shannon ever writing a "proposal of research". They just did whatever that came to mind, and they did everything, so do many researchers today. Certainly researchers often had a specialization, but nobody is fully defined by that specialization. The Nobel prize awardees from just past week showed that you can be a researcher at developing game AI, but your skill can also be used for computational chemistry. Or you can by a computer scientist working on memory, but your research might ultimately prove beneficial for physics. How do you ever account for the spontaneous, interdisciplinary nature of research in a proposal?


I can't see any way of writing a research proposal that is not at a very abstract and high-level, e.g., "for the betterment of humanity" or "discover the nature of intelligence" or some trite like that. If you were to write it like that, then everything naturally falls under your research proposal, but it is also meaningless. Furthermore, if I actually knew what research I wanted to do, then I might not even do them because I already know how to do them. I do the research that I do not know how to do.
Given all this, does the idea of a research proposal actually make sense in today's world?

This feels like a rant disguised as a question. I mean, does it really matter what any of us think? You’ll still need to write those damn research proposals…

Give me money so I can take a shower, have a good night sleep, and maybe I will have a good idea. Strange that that pitch does not work so well....

I don't understand. You say "does the idea of a research proposal actually make sense in today's world?" Are you implying that it made sense in yesterday's world? The world of von Neumann and Shannon?

Nobel-prize winning research has been funded by research proposals, so the distinctions you make do not seem to align with reality. Also even in AI/ML, people do have research agendas, you are massively confusing different concepts.

I think your confusion about the value of research proposals is best resolved in quotes along the lines of "In preparing for battle I have always found that plans are useless, but planning is indispensable." https://quoteinvestigator.com/2017/11/18/planning/ Simply put, by not having a plan you ensure failure. That's true for war as well as leading a research group as a professor.

Is it the case you’re just starting out on a research career, a student? You don’t need a research proposal, but keep in mind you’ll be competing against others who do have one.

If you do any sort of null hypothesis significance testing then you absolutely need a research proposal and detailed plan before you get started for your work to have any validity; if anything, academics probably put too little effort towards those sorts of proposals.

Here's a proposal by Shannon, Minsky, Rochester, and McCarthy: http://jmc.stanford.edu/articles/dartmouth/dartmouth.pdf I do wish proposals of that length would still be successful.

On the one hand, I agree that research proposals in job applications are not particularly useful for explaining a candidate's research trajectory, as the committee can easily discern this from their previous work and publications.
However, it's misleading to suggest that research occurs without a clear, preconceived direction—simply based on whatever the researcher happens to be thinking at the time. This couldn’t be further from the truth. Most independent researchers have a vision or a clear sense of where their work is heading. Those without such direction are not truly independent researchers.
The primary purpose of a research proposal, along with many other requirements in the application process, is to demonstrate that the candidate possesses the dedication, patience, determination, and persistence to complete these tasks. A candidate unwilling to put effort into writing a thoughtful proposal may signal a lack of motivation and reliability, casting doubt on their long-term effectiveness as an employee.

There is an aspect of different scales of planning to consider:

On the grand scale, it's useful for a researcher to know what they are planning to develop long-term: a vision for the general direction that will be taken for at least a couple of years worth of time.

There's the coarse scale, where this long-term vision is chopped into work that might get distributed into individual Ph.D. projects. This is something that can still be planned for.

And there's the fine scale, where research gets divided into individual publications, individual month-to-month or even day-to-day ideas.


It seems that you're mostly concerned about the finest scale - the month-to-month or day-to-day ideas, the shower thoughts, and momentary insights, which indeed you cannot plan for. But by having the grand scale and the coarse scale in place, you prime your mind to figure out the fine scale as you go.
A research proposal should be at just the right scale, which I would say spans between grand to coarse, and maybe just gently touches on an aspect of fine but just to show that you already have a specific detail in mind that can kickstart your work. A proposal should still grant the researcher enough flexibility to respond to the fine-scale ideas and findings and to position them somewhere in the grand and coarse plans.
Professor Howard Stone talks about this in this podcast episode:
42 | Howard Stone on how to tilt your head for discovery

This might depend on what country you're in, but I suspect in many cases what they're really looking for with a research proposal is "are you able to write a good grant application?"
In an ideal world, all researchers would have enough government funding to explore research directions, take chances, be spontaneous, etc.
But we don't live in that world. First off, the university is taking a financial risk hiring you. They want to tell the difference between someone who will lead to published results, which helps their reputation, and someone who is just going to take a salary and do nothing. Having a plan shows that you've at least thought about what research to do.
But more importantly, most universities don't have funding to hire a lot of grad students. So they need professors to apply for grants. And you apply for grants by writing research proposals.
So any candidates who aren't able to "play the game" of talking about their research aren't likely to bring much grant money into the university.
Is it fair? Probably not. But on the other hand, what's the use of research if you don't communicate your findings? Communication is part of research, and institutions want to hire people who can communicate.

The NIH budget, all dedicated to medical-related research, is 5 times the NSF budget, which covers all of the rest of science and engineering, plus mathematics and some social sciences.  Private funding (in the US) is similarly skewed.
This means that practices that work for medicine end up being the practices that are used across all subjects, because if you're going to have one way of doing things, then it makes sense for it to be the way that makes sense for most of the money.  In part, this is because, due to the money (and the administrative skills biologists have to learn to manage all the money), a disproportionate number of Deans are biologists.
In health-related research, most of the labor goes not into generating ideas but rather into collecting data, lots and lots of data that takes a large amount of time and expense to collect.  Data collection can indeed be planned, and, indeed, has to be planned.  If you don't plan your data collection well, you get a bunch of useless data (because the data ends up being too disorganized to do statistics with).  All the idea generation is already done by the time the grant proposal is written; all that is left to do is the execution of the data collection and analysis.  (Ideally, the analysis is planned before the data gathering, because allowing plans for analysis to be affected by the data can lead to statistical biases.)
Now, the biology paradigm works less well for fields where less (or none) of the research work is data collection that can (and should be) planned in advance.  But we are stuck with it, because universities and governments don't want to create a different format for a small percentage of the budget.  Every NSF Program Officer in Mathematics knows that the standard format grant proposal makes no sense in Mathematics; they just allow - in fact encourage - more appropriately written proposals which don't follow the standard format (but still follow all the formatting requirements) with a wink and a nod.
